# Why is JVM process RAM getting bigger (1GB+) even if my heap and non-heap are capped at 128M?

Tags: java, linux, docker, memory-leaks, chromium-embedded

I have got a docker container running a java process which the Resident Size (RSS) keeps getting up (1GB+), even if the MaxHeapMemory is set to 128m. There are no threads being created (they are 32), the are no classes being loaded (~5000).

I am using JNI to communicate to Chromium Embedded Framework (jcef)

Profiling the JVM, it consumes 128M for Heap and about 50M for Non-Heap.

It takes about a day to get to 1GB, however it never stops growing.

Curious thing: if I run it on OSX without docker, the memory stays fine.

Anyone have had this problem before? Any bug in libc for instance? Any hint?

Best,

Comment: This may be memory taken by native libraries. Do you have any ?

Comment: Yes, libjcef.so which is the interface for CEF. How can I dump it to see if that is it? Also, wouldn't that appear in the Non-Heap space?

Comment: it depends of your operating system. For windows, use systinternal tools and for linux memstat should do it.

Comment: with memstat I get 244932k of usage and is not increasing (up and down). on htop it shows around 500 and increasing.